# Common List Index Out Of Range Issue, Why?

Tags: python, list, math, scipy, sequence

```
import scipy.special


s = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3,
     1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4,
     1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3,
     1, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5,
     1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 3,
     1, 2, 1, 4, 1]


r = []

for n in range(20):
 result = 1
 for k in range(n-1):
     result += (scipy.special.binom(n - 1, k) % 2) * r[s[n - k - 1]]
 r.append(result)


def binomial_transform(sequence):
    n = len(sequence)
    result = [0] * n
    
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            result[i] += sequence[j] * scipy.special.binom(i, j)
    
    return result

sequence = r
binomial_result = binomial_transform(sequence)
print(binomial_result)
```

I tried playing with where result began, 0 instead of 1, tried having r initialized with 1 as an element instead of it being empty, tried maybe instead of k in range n-1, k in range n.The code worked perfectly when the list, s, was the oeis sequence A000120, and it produced, as expected, oeis  A101911. now that i changed it from  A000120 to A001511 it says list index out of range. This has driven me crazy. If i just add another number to the front of s, it compiles without error, but if delete an element, there's an error.

Comment: If it's driving you crazy, start logging. You're getting the error on line 17, so: log `n` and `k` before that line. You'll see `n` is 2, `k` is 0, and `s[n - k - 1]` is 2. So: what size is `r` at this point? And what would you imagine happens when you try to access `r[2]`.

Comment: Uh sorry i don't get it, what do you mean by logging? really appreciate the speedy response by the way

Comment: literally logging all the variables you're making use of. `print(n, k, s[n - k - 1], len(r))` because you can't solve a problem if you don't know the problem: log your variables, to start understanding the problem.

Comment: oh awesome, you even mentioned it, there's an issue with r[2]. Though Im a bit stumped

Comment: Now you know the problem, work backwards: should `r` be bigger than 2 elements that at this point? Then look at the code in your loop to see where you're growing `r` and whether you did that correctly (because if things error, the conclusion we already have is that it's not). Should it _not_ be bigger? In that case, rethink what element you _should_ be accessing instead of `s[n - k - 1]`.

Comment: Your inner loop doesn't run at all until `n == 2`. At that point the first iteration of the inner loop is `n - k - 1 == 1` then `s[1] == 2` and `r[2]` is an index error at this point. Because `r` is `[1, 1]` (from the first two outer loops where the inner loop didn't run).

Comment: oh i think i got it, should i be accessing r[s[n - k - 1]-1]?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for j in range(i+1):`, what do you think will be the largest possible value of `j`? Do you expect that value to be a valid index for `sequence`? Why or why not? Given that `n` is the name you used for the length of `sequence`, in terms of `n`, what do you think are the valid indices for `sequence`? What do you think is the first valid index? What do you think is the last valid index?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. When you say "This has driven me crazy.", I sympathize; but fixing problems is about *analyzing* them in an *organized* way - not about getting aggravated or experimenting without any plan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer just makes more explicit the observations of several of the comments.

The marked duplicate isn't particularly useful, since it focuses on the common case of indexing the `nth` time of a list that is n items long.  Here the problem is with using an intermediate indexing array that may have values that are too large.

When I run part of your code, I get:

```
In [2]: len(s)
Out[2]: 105
In [3]: r = []
   ...: 
   ...: for n in range(20):
   ...:  result = 1
   ...:  for k in range(n-1):
   ...:      result += (scipy.special.binom(n - 1, k) % 2) * r[s[n - k - 1]]
   ...:  r.append(result)
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 6
      4 result = 1
      5 for k in range(n-1):
----> 6     result += (scipy.special.binom(n - 1, k) % 2) * r[s[n - k - 1]]
      7 r.append(result)
```

and the `ipython` display highlights the `r[s[n - k - 1]]` expression.

Lets try it again with some prints:

```
In [5]: r = []
   ...: for n in range(20):
   ...:  result = 1
   ...:  for k in range(n-1):
   ...:      print(n,k, len(r), len(s),n-k-1)
   ...:      print(r[s[n - k - 1]])
   ...:      result += (scipy.special.binom(n - 1, k) % 2) * r[s[n - k - 1]]
   ...:  r.append(result)
   ...:  print(n,r)
   ...: 
0 [1]
1 [1, 1]
2 0 2 105 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 6
      4 for k in range(n-1):
      5     print(n,k, len(r), len(s),n-k-1)
----> 6     print(r[s[n - k - 1]])
      7     result += (scipy.special.binom(n - 1, k) % 2) * r[s[n - k - 1]]
      8 r.append(result)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

So after a couple of loops, `n=2`, `r` has 2 terms.

`n-k-1` is 2-0-1=1.  `s[1]` is `2`.  `r[2]` raises the error.  I don't know why you are selecting elements of `s` as indices for the `r`.  `r` starts empty, and grows with each append.  But the values of `s` are not linked, in any obvious way, to the size of `r`.  They range from 1 to 7 in a seemingly random way.

A tweak like `r[s[n - k - 1]-1]` solve things for this `n`, but what about a later `s`?

Trying it, it does run through to  n=19, with the resulting `r`:

```
19 [1, 1, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 10.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0, 8.0, 8.0, 23.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0]
```

Again this depends on the values of `s`.  With the added `-1`, the `r` indexing ranges from `[0,6]`. So if the `6` isn't too early in the loop, it runs.  But without knowing anything about `s`, this fix looks like a kludge.